# How to do Segmentation in Facebook AR Studio

Tags: facebook, augmented-reality, image-segmentation

I recently started working on FaceBook AR Studio ([FaceBook AR Studio Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ar-studio). What I am trying to do is add "Segmentation", as listed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ar-studio/before-you-start/features) in the available features, but I am unable to do so.

When I go to AR Studio project and navigate to 'Insert', I only get 2 options in the "Scene Understanding" category. Those 2 options are -> 'Face Tracker" and "Plane Tracker". Nothing about segmentation is there (but if you look at the tutorials FaceBook has provided, segmentation is listed under the category). I am Running v35 of FB AR Studio.

Can you help me understand how I am supposed to do segmentation because it's still listed as a feature of FaceBook AR Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You must update to V39 to use segmentation.